# Find the number of todonotes (from the previous run)

Tags: pdftex, lists, counters, tocloft

I would like to have a small '\if' there are todonotes; then show a large warning and list of todonotes on the first page. And otherwise don't.

I've got no trouble accessing the todonotes counter:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}
%\ifthenelse{ someCounter > 0}{Warning - todos left! \listoftodos\pagebreak}{}

\listoftodos

It is initially to 0=\arabic{@todonotes@numberoftodonotes}

Hello \todo{One thing to do} World\todo{A second things to do}.

And it is now  2=\arabic{@todonotes@numberoftodonotes}
\end{document}
```

But the @todonotes@numberoftodonotes is reset to 0 on each run. So I would like to find that count for the listoftodos -- which on the second run is populated.

How to best do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the number of `\contentsline` calls in the `\listoftodos`, this way you know the number of todos, but only after `\listoftodos`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcounter{totalnumberoftodos}

\newcommand\patchcontentsline
  {%
    \xpretocmd\contentsline{\stepcounter{totalnumberoftodos}}{}{}%
  }
\xpretocmd\listoftodos{\begingroup\patchcontentsline}{}{}
\xapptocmd\listoftodos{\endgroup}{}{}

\begin{document}
%\ifthenelse{ someCounter > 0}{Warning - todos left! \listoftodos\pagebreak}{}

\listoftodos

The total number of todo-notes was \arabic{totalnumberoftodos}.

It is initially to 0=\arabic{@todonotes@numberoftodonotes}

Hello \todo{One thing to do} World\todo{A second things to do}.

And it is now  2=\arabic{@todonotes@numberoftodonotes}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** A version that doesn't need `\listoftodos` to be used:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument
  {%
    \immediate\write\@auxout
      {\gdef\noexpand\totaltodos{\the\value{@todonotes@numberoftodonotes}}}%
  }
\newcommand*\iftodos
  {%
    \@ifundefined{totaltodos}
      {}
      {%
        \ifnum\totaltodos>0
          \expandafter\@secondoftwo
        \fi
        \@gobble
      }%
  }
\@ifundefined{totaltodos}{\def\totaltodos{0}}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\iftodos
  {%
    Warning - todos left!
    \listoftodos\newpage
  }

The total number of todo-notes was \totaltodos.

It is initially to 0=\arabic{@todonotes@numberoftodonotes}

Hello \todo{One thing to do} World\todo{A second things to do}.

And it is now  2=\arabic{@todonotes@numberoftodonotes}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So the puzzle I have is that `only after \listoftodos'. Because if I run this *without* showing the list (i.e. if that was in that if-then-else statement) -- the number is 0.
 Is there perhaps any way one can run the \listsoftodos without actually showing them. So you then can get the count - and include them if the count is > 0 (with large warning banners) and skip it all - if not ?

Comment: @Dirk-WillemvanGulik you can do a `\setbox0\vbox{\listoftodos}`, but if you don't want to print the todos anyway, we can get the count in a better way.

Comment: @Dirk-WillemvanGulik see my edit for a version that doesn't need `\listoftodos` to be used.

Comment: Oddly enough - I get a `Undefined control sequence' on that totaltodos (in pdflatex).

Comment: @Dirk-WillemvanGulik you have to use it after `\begin{document}`, as the aux-file is read in there. If you don't want this, one could also write the counter into another file, not the aux, and read in that one if it exists.

Comment: Odd - I keep getting that - just form a cut & paste of the second example you gave. Does it need a special versin of latex ?

Comment: @Dirk-WillemvanGulik my bad, the second version did never test whether `\listoftodos` is already defined, now this should be fixed.

Comment: Thank you - works absolutely splendidly !

Answer (score 2):

The package `totcount` is what you're looking for.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{totcount}

\regtotcounter{@todonotes@numberoftodonotes}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \ifnum\totvalue{@todonotes@numberoftodonotes}>0
    Warning --- todos left! \listoftodos\clearpage
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

It is initially to 0=\arabic{@todonotes@numberoftodonotes}

Hello \todo{One thing to do} World\todo{A second things to do}.

And it is now  2=\arabic{@todonotes@numberoftodonotes}

\end{document}
```

Be sure to run LaTeX twice.

Comment: Yes - that solves it most perfectly & comprehensively -- and thanks for the `totcount' hint - most useful for other things as well.